# How to prove the Cauchy sequence using the definition

Tags: real-analysis

Use the definition of a Cauchy sequence to prove that the sequence defined by  $x_n = \left (\frac{3}{2}\right )^n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But it's not Cauchy.

Comment: Did you mean $(2/3)^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is *not* a Cauchy sequence.

In order to show this, let $m$ and $n$ be any natural numbers such that $m <n$. Then we note that
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert x_m - x_n \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^m - \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^n \right\rvert \\
&= \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^n - \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^m \\
&= \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^m  \left[ \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{n-m} - 1 \right] \\
&\geq \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \left[ \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) - 1 \right] \\
&= \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Thus if we take a real number $\varepsilon$ such that 
$$ 0 < \varepsilon < \frac{3}{4}, $$
then for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \neq n$, we would get
$$ \left\lvert x_m - x_n \right\rvert > \varepsilon, $$
and therefore for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find some $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m > N$ and $n > N$, but 
$$ \left\lvert x_m - x_n \right\rvert \not\leq \varepsilon. $$

Answer (score 1):

This sequence is not Cauchy.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, then every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges, but you can clearly see that $\left (\frac{3}{2}\right )^n \to \infty$.